# Use parent scope field as variable in inner scope

Tags: graphql

I have a query,

```
query {
    foo {
        baz

        bar (barBaz: baz) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

How would I get the value of `foo.baz` to then use it as a filter in `foo.bar`?

Comment: no variable needed ... [usually] 1st resolver param = parent [usually with [direct] values resolved earlier]

Comment: What if it is nested further? As in getting a value from the grandparent

Comment: can be read [and provided cascading] by parent and assigned to some extra (removed later from response) field/property